# The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type DataBase

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm having trouble creating a class that create and manipulate the database! But the method `create ()` has a problem saying

> "The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for
> the type BancoDeDados".

Anyone have any suggestions to overcome this problem? My code is as follows:

```java
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DataBase{
     private SQLiteDatabase db;
     private String DATABASE_NAME;
     private String TABLE_NAME;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ALL;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ID;
     private String SQL_CREATE;
     
     public DataBase(SQLiteDatabase db,String DATABASE_NAME,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_SELECT_ID,String SQL_CREATE){
         this.db = db;
         this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
         this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ID = SQL_SELECT_ID;
         this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
     }
     
     public void create(){
         this.db = openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         this.db.execSQL(this.SQL_CREATE);
         this.db.close(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Use Sqlite helper http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: where have you `openOrCreateDatabase()` method defined? show code of this method..

Comment: looks like you want to use this static method of SQLiteDatabase? `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(//....` ? Anyhow, you didn't define such a method in your class, so it's no surprize that it is not found.

Comment: Yes, but when I use this.db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(//.... does not work either!

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteOpenHelper is used to create a database in Android.
You need to override the onCreate method after extending this class.
`db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);` in onCreate creates the database.
TABLE_CREATE is your DDL String.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     //The database name and version can be parameterized in the constructor.
     public DbHelper(Context context, String databaseName, int databaseVersion) {
         super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
     }



    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite
     * .SQLiteDatabase)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            // Create Database
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite
     * .SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



}
```

Comment: But I need to create multiple reuse database. Need to use the String DATABASE_NAME.

Comment: @carlosgoes2008 Do you mean to say multiple tables or multiple databases?

Comment: @carlosgoes2008 Okay, I understand. Edited the answer. You create an object of this helper class by passing databaseName and version as parameters. Then you can call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase on this object to manipulate the Database.

Comment: how I  initialize the variable Context context  in Main.java ? Because here gave error during creation of BD.

Comment: Are you calling this from an Activity? You can use the function getApplicationContext() @carlosgoes2008

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to create this `class to create and manipulate database` is `repackage` it and besides `this class EXTENDS NO need no other!`

> `Under My class after you solve the problem '.` DataBase.java`

```java
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 public class DataBase{
     private String DATABASE_NAME;
     private int DATABASE_VERSION;
     private String TABLE_NAME;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ALL;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ID;
     private String SQL_CREATE;
     
     public DataBase(String DATABASE_NAME,int DATABASE_VERSION,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_SELECT_ID,String SQL_CREATE){
         this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
         this.DATABASE_VERSION = DATABASE_VERSION;
         this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ID = SQL_SELECT_ID;
         this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
     }
     public DataBase(String DATABASE_NAME,int DATABASE_VERSION,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_CREATE){
         this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
         this.DATABASE_VERSION = DATABASE_VERSION;
         this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
         this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
     }

    public void onCreate(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
         db.execSQL(this.SQL_CREATE); //Criando tabela caso não exista!!
         db.close();
     }
     
    public void onUpgrade(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + this.TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(ctx,db);
     }
     
     public long onWrite(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,String row,ContentValues ctv){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         long lg = db.insert(this.TABLE_NAME,row,ctv);
         db.close();
         return lg;
     }
     
     public int onUpdate(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,ContentValues ctv,String row,int id){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
          int x = db.update(this.TABLE_NAME, ctv, row, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
         db.close();
         return x;
     }
     
     public Cursor onSelecAll(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(this.SQL_SELECT_ALL, null);
         return cursor;
     }
     
     public Cursor onSelecId(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,int id){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_SELECT_ID, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
          return cursor;
      }
     
     public int onDelete(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,String row,int id){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         int x = db.delete(this.TABLE_NAME, row, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
         db.close();
         return x;
     }
     
     public void onClose(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
         db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         db.close();
     }
}
```

> And in `Main.java`:

```java
import android...

public class Main extends Activity {
     
     private SQLiteDatabase db;
     private Context ctx;
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
     private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table";
     private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
     private static final String SQL_SELECT_ID = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id = ?";
     /* SQL de criação do banco de dados. */
     private static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "person VARCHAR(30), " 
                        "animal VARCHAR(30))";
     BancoDeDados BD = new BancoDeDados(DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_VERSION,TABLE_NAME,SQL_SELECT_ALL,SQL_SELECT_ID,SQL_CREATE);
      @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        ctx = getBaseContext(); //Context to use in class BancoDeDados
        BD.onCreate(ctx, db); // Create BD and table if needed!! 
       /* .... */
     }
    }
```